# Apache server not responding on xampp

Tags: apache, xampp

I know this question has been asked before, but I upgraded to windows 10. My xampp was working fine before the upgrade and now it is not. Apache does not run now. I had problems with skype before, so I removed it, which freed the port for apache.

```
    2:06:09 PM  [Apache]    Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
2:06:09 PM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
2:06:09 PM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
2:06:09 PM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

Is there any way I can find out what is using that port and stop it? I have tried changing the port number in the config file to 8080, but it does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Here are the error logs after I changed the port to 8080:

```
[Thu Aug 27 14:10:10.207404 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3576:tid 524] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Aug 27 14:10:10.583181 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3576:tid 524] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Aug 27 14:10:10.755107 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3576:tid 524] AH00455: Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.6.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 27 14:10:10.755107 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3576:tid 524] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul 12 2015 10:56:48
[Thu Aug 27 14:10:10.755107 2015] [core:notice] [pid 3576:tid 524] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/XAMPP/apache'
[Thu Aug 27 14:10:10.770732 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3576:tid 524] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 10308
[Thu Aug 27 14:10:12.035120 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 10308:tid 572] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Aug 27 14:10:12.395328 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 10308:tid 572] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Aug 27 14:10:12.535958 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10308:tid 572] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: Ca nyou give us the error logs ?

Comment: I am sorry, when I looked into the error logs it is empty.